# Moving data from multiple csv files to xlsx files

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl, xlsx

I have a folder that contains 2 more folders. Inside each folder is a csv and xlsx file.

Ex:

- test (folder 1)

  - test.csv
  - test.xlsx
- test2 (folder 2)

  - test2.csv
  - test2.xlsx

I have a working script that moves data from a csv file to a xlsx file.

Say ‘test.csv’ contains the following data:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| test.com | yes |
| test.com/dl | no |
| 1.1.1.1 | yes |

The code below will move that data into test.xlsx:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv

wb = load_workbook(“D:\\local\\test\\test\\test.xlsx”)
ws = wb.active
with open(“D:\\local\\test\\test\\test.csv”, ‘r’) as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        ws.append(row)
wb.save(“D:\\local\\test\\test\\test.xlsx”)
```

Is there an easy way to move all data from ‘test.csv’ to ‘test.xlsx’ and ‘test2.csv’ to ‘test2.xlsx’ at once? The names of the csv and xlsx files will not always be the same but the location will.

I have tried the following but it returns a traceback error:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import csv

wb = load_workbook(“D:\\local\\test\\{}\\{}.xlsx”)
ws = wb.active
with open(“D:\\local\\test\\{}\\{}.csv”, ‘r’) as f:
    for row in csv.reader(f):
        ws.append(row)
wb.save(“D:\\local\\test\\{}\\{}.xlsx”)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are wanting to iterate through the files in a folder… look into the `os` module.

Comment: @Jarvis can I just use the os module or do I need to use it along with my current code?

Comment: [This may prove useful](https://pythongeeks.org/python-os-module/)

Comment: @GooseCake In addition to the code you already have. The `os` module gives you access to the Operating System. The link provided by @cybernetic.nomad should help you along in using it to find the files you want to convert.

Comment: `os.path.listdir()`

Comment: @Jarvis I have tried reading through the documentation.

I can add:

path = “D:\\local\\test”

print(os.listdir(path))

And this prints [‘test’, ‘test2’] so I know if sees the folders… I can’t figure out how to manipulate it to work with openpyxl because even thought it sees it when I run the code I get a traceback error that reads “FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: “D:\\local\\test\\{}\\{}.xlsx”.

Comment: What are the `{}` for in the path? It is in all three…

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `.xlsx` files already exist and are empty, you can use the code below to copy the content of multiple `.csv` files to those `.xlsx` files (that have the same stem/filename).

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

directory = r'D:\local\test'

for file in Path(directory).glob('*/*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(file, encoding='utf-8-sig')
    excel_path = os.path.splitext(file)[0]+'.xlsx'
    wb = load_workbook(excel_path)
    ws = wb.active
    for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
        ws.append(r)
        wb.save(excel_path)
```